Meaning of "tunnels" in "The Holy State" by Thomas Fuller
I chanced across the following quote from The Holy State (1642) by Thomas Fuller (1608–1661). Page 199 says:

It is a vanity to persuade the world one hath much learning, by getting a great library.  As soon shall I believe everyone is valiant that hath a well-furnished armoury. I guess good housekeeping by the smoking, not the number of the tunnels, as knowing that many of them, built merely for uniformity, are without chimneys, and more without fires."

I thought this was very clever, but was baffled by the use of the word 'tunnels'.

I think that in this passage it is not too difficult to guess the meaning from the context. Fuller says that he judges the quality of the housekeeping by the smoke that rises from the house, not by the number of “tunnels”, because some of the tunnels lack chimneys. So by “tunnels” he must mean “flues” (the pipes leading from fireplaces to chimneys). Looking in a comprehensive dictionary, we can confirm this:

tunnel, n., 2.a. The shaft or flue of a chimney. Obsolete.
1680   The tunnells of the chimneys were carried into the middle of the howse.  
J. Aubrey, Brief Lives: Bacon (1898) vol. I. 78
Oxford English Dictionary.

Fuller’s point is that flues may be decorative rather than practical, just as books may be bought for display rather than for reading.
(Fuller’s analogy seems odd to me, since chimneys are visible from outside a house and flues are usually not, so that declining to judge a house by counting the chimneys would be more apposite. But I see no way to interpret him as saying this.)

"Formerly, when 'chimney' meant a fireplace, a tunnel often meant a chimney or flue" (An Etymological Dictionary of the English Language, Sleat, 1882). To Fuller, the fireplace itself is the chimney (but it may not have a fire in it!), and what we would now call the chimney ("structure through which smoke or steam is carried up away from a fire, etc. and through the roof", per Oxford Learner's Dictionary, thus including the flue) is a "tunnel" (including the part visible from outside).

Or if he had said "not by the number chimneys, but by the number of smoking tunnels". It would have been better if it had been shorter, but still a great line.
I'll have to find that dictionary!
Thanks.
